# How to get paginated answer's response?

Tags: django, pagination

I am using django as backend for website

There will be 10 qwestions
 i want to paginate them (one qwestion's ans is given then go to next so on ) and atlast give marks calculated based on all the answers given

Any hints on how to do it?

I found somthing similar but dont know how to implement in django

[What's the most efficient way to calculate a running total/balance when using pagination (PHP, MySQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38503981/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-calculate-a-running-total-balance-when-using-pa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked to Django Pagination docs?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/

From that page

Your view:

```
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from django.shortcuts import render

def listing(request):
    contact_list = Contacts.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 25) # 25 is the items per page, in Your case would be 1

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render(request, 'list.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

Your template:

```
{% for contact in contacts %}
    {# Each "contact" is a Contact model object. #}
    {{ contact.full_name|upper }}<br>
    ...
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if contacts.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ contacts.number }} of {{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if contacts.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ contacts.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

To go to a page you should add to the url `?page=1` where 1 is the page number.

Comment: I have no problem implementing pagination what i want to do is calculate the score based on the correct answers        ,  if all the qwestions were in the same page one single response could be used to send all answers   and finally calculate the score  . Since the qwestions are paginated how to keep track of answers to previous qwestions, whether they were right/wrong , how much marks were obtained etc

Comment: At first, I see two different solutions to your problem. You can not use server pagination, that is, serve all the questions on one page but simulate de pagination with javascript. That way, you can send all the questions in one request. Alternative you can use server pagination but create a model named Questionary, or something similar, a Question has a foreign key to Questionary. When you serve the first Question also you create a Questionary, and so on. When the user answers the last question you can get all the related questions by the questionary.